# CGAffineTransform Scale wont scale if using variables

Tags: swift, avfoundation, core-graphics

This is driving me crazy. 
Im applying a scale transform, if I type numbers statically, it scales perfectly well. but if I use variables it always reset's to 1.0. But I even print the new transform and the scale is applied.

This works:

```
let scaleTransform = origTranform.scaledBy(x: 0.28125, y: 0.28125)
```

This doesn't

```
let s = finalVideoFrame.height/size.height;
let scaleTransform = origTranform.scaledBy(x: s, y: s)
```

if I print scaleTransform I get the right values on either cases.

```
▿ CGAffineTransform
  - a : 0.28125
  - b : 0.0
  - c : 0.0
  - d : 0.28125
  - tx : 0.0
  - ty : 0.0
```

Im using this transfom to set it for a **AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction**

Comment: "but if I use variables it always reset's to 1.0" Sorry, I don't understand those words. If it prints correctly, in what sense does it "reset to 1"?

Comment: @matt in the sense that the compiled video shows no modification in scale. It shows just like if I had typed 1.0. but it is actually 0.28125 when I assigned it. And if I literally just type the numbers it works.

Comment: I can see why that would be mystifying. I’d even say it’s impossible. Could it be something about the state of the variables at the time you fetch them?

Comment: Can you post an example project that demonstrates this difference between using a variable and using a hard-coded value? I'm finding it difficult to believe.

Comment: Im so desperate Im going to share the project, and specify the function that does it. gimme a minute.

Comment: @matt here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3c54ba707ca7165e0b01ae6ca91a85da20181222052304/3289e8 you can go to file G8Recorder.swift line 450. To replicate. PressHold to record a short video with selfieCamera, then tap the switch that is below the top left "window" icon.. it will render a landscape image, now record a few more seconds. Then press DONE. You will see the transform printed in the console.

Comment: How are you applying the `scaleTransform` to the video? What function are you calling to set it?

Comment: @user1118321 the scaleTransform is applied to a 'AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction' which is added to an array of instructions to be later assigned to a 'AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction' which is used by a 'AVMutableVideoComposition' which is finally used by AVAssetExportSession. 
see line 373 that's when I save the instruction that contains the transform.

Comment: Could this be a threading problem? That is the sort of thing I meant by "the state of the variables at the time you fetch them". It looks like this code might be executed on a non-main thread. Could there be some sort of cross-thread dependency here?

Comment: you know what. Im starting to think is related to how I do the layerInstructions. It might be just listening to the first transform and not care for subsequent transform for the second video.